# How can i edit the icon & name of a shourtcut in the unity menu?

Tags: icons

like changing the name(1) and icon(2) of the app

the example image(1,2)
[image: the example image(1,2)]

Comment: It's not unity menu. It is "All Applications" under gnome shell not unity.

Answer (score 0):

**Default, manual way**

By default, there is no graphical tool to do this. You can, however, do this quite easily in the manual way.

1. Find the `.desktop` launcher for the app you want to change in the folder `/usr/share/applications`
2. Copy that file to your local `.local/share/applications` folder.
3. Open the copy in a text editor. Find the line that starts with `Name=` and change that to what you want to see in the menu. Find the line that starts with `Icon=` and change that to what you want this to be.

You can specify a full path name to the icon. Alternatively, if you place your icon in your local `.icons` or `.local/share/icons` folder, then you can just specify the basename of the icon file, i.e., the first part of the file name without the extension.

Your edited copy takes precedence over the system wide installed copy. So potential future upgrades will not undo your changes.

**Graphical tool**

A utility "MenuLibre" can be installed that provides a GUI to do such changes.